# Angular Material progress spinner in-line

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is it possible to have the [Angular Material progress spinner](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/overview) appear in-line with the text and roughly the size of a character?

I want something like:

```
<span>please wait <mat-spinner></mat-spinner></span>
```

where the spinner just appears in-line with the 'please wait' text.

Is this possible?

I have had a look at the docs and the [examples](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/examples) provided but none of them seem to offer a way forward and a Google + search of StackOverflow didn't turn anything up.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `display: flex` on the wrapping element. To set the size of it, you can use the `diameter` input:

```
<div class="spinner-wrapper">
  <span>please wait</span>
  <mat-spinner [diameter]="12"></mat-spinner>
</div>

.spinner-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

See a working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q2folh-4noc28)

Comment: Thanks - That moves it in-line with the text but doesn't change the size to roughly the same height as a character

Comment: @Stewart_R you can use the `diameter` input. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

you can also use *display:inline*. you just have to declare mat-spinner between span or p tag

```css
.spinner{
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner">
  <p>please wait <mat-spinner [diameter]="12"> </mat-spinner> </p>
</div>
```